# Manipulate Spring MVC model fields for JSP output

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a model like this defined...

```
public class Product{
  private long timestamp;
  // get/set follows...
}
```

The timestamp field is fine for the database, since I persist the data via JPA. However, in the JSP output, I don't want to present the timestamp as long, I want to present it as a customized String. I would like to define the long/String conversion in a custom method.

I could convert the timestamp field to DateTime or something, but this is a general question - how is it possible to process model data without modifying the model itself, because it's just for the view? I looked into [Spring Conversion](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) and Formatter SPIs, but that doesn't seem to fit here (Formatter is mainly for user input, Conversion applies to the whole model and I just want to manipulate one field of the model).

I already thought of creating a new object just for the view, passing all the data from the database model and manipulate it there, but there must be a better solution...

**EDIT**

Some additonal code...here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/")
public ModelAndView getAllProducts() {
    List<Product> products = daoReader.findAllProducts();

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("myproductview");
    mv.addObject("products", products);

    return mv;
```

And this is the JSP (simplified):

```
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="currentproduct">
        <tr>
            <td>${currentproduct.timestamp}</td>
            <td>${currentproduct.name}</td>
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring views normally use getters and setters to access the data of a model.  The best solution would be to provide a getter that formats the date or convert the `long` object to a `Date` object or some other required format.  From the views, you then access this getter method.

**EDIT**

```
public class Product{
  private long timestamp;

  public Date getDate() {
        return new Date(timestamp);
  }
}
```

and from the view

```
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="currentproduct">
        <tr>
            <td>${currentproduct.date}</td>
            <td>${currentproduct.name}</td>
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Is the answer above what you mean or do you know any solution without using custom JSP tags?

Comment: this solution that I gave is without using custom JSP tags and it works.

Comment: Can you point me to some working example/tutorial? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, this is indeed much simpler and works fine - thanks! However, it means to add functionality to the model, something I wanted to avoid since I cannot estimate whether that might be a problem/inefficient. So, the first answer from Ralph is also good, since it leaves the model untouched. Thanks!

Comment: @Jan Petzold: This is my first answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a "special" getter that returns a formated string?

Or a JSP Tag that does the formatting like:
jsp:

```
 <td><my:formatLongTimestamIntoSomethingUsefull
        value="${currentproduct.timestamp}"/></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, see my edit above. Problem is that I put the model in a List<Product>, which I want to display in a table. So in the table, there are about 20 properties (=fields) to display in different cells, and just one property is to be formatted.

If I would implement my own getter for the "timestamp" property I'd lose the possibility to run it all in a loop, right?

Comment: No, add this getter:  `String getFormatedTimeStanp() {return new Date(this.timestamp);...}`  and then use ${currentproduct.fromatedtimestamp}`

Comment: Thanks. That worked, with the additional help of [viralpatel](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/tutorial-create-custom-tag-library-taglib-in-jsp.html) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637302/passing-a-java-object-value-in-custom-jsp-tag). Still feels a bit complicated to me, but maybe thats just because I'm coming from the PHP world :)